# Does ffmpeg support GPU acceleration on Jetson platform?

Tags: ffmpeg, decoder, nvidia-jetson-nano, zoneminder

- I want to run **ZoneMinder** on Jetson-nano as an IP CAM server, but it seems that Jetson nano can not handle many cams which are using **ffmpeg** for decoding.
- If I open three cams on **ZoneMinder**, *CPU usage is always* **100%**, but GPU usage is 0%, and I can not open more cams.

#### FFMPEG without hardware acceleration?

In this [discussion](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ffmpeg-using-hardware-gpu-cuda/72312), the NV Moderator said that

> ffmpeg with GPU support is not enabled on Jetson platform ...

I know that NVENC/NVDEC can help ffmpeg hardware acceleration, but these hardware blocks are being now executed on CPU, not on the GPU.

#### Custom FFMPEG for jetson-nano don't support GPU acceleration?

I found this [jetson-ffmpeg](https://github.com/jocover/jetson-ffmpeg) repo, can this repo use GPU acceleration? Because I tried but didn't work (still using NVENC/NVDEC acceleration of CPU).

If GPU on Jetson nano is sure that can not support ffmpeg acceleration, but I want to use ZoneMinder, is there a better way to solve this problem? e.g. using GStreamer?

Comment: Isn't NVENC a feature of the *GPU*? Did you see [this issue](https://github.com/jocover/jetson-ffmpeg/issues/42)?

Comment: In [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/ffmpeg-using-hardware-gpu-cuda/72312/13) discussion, it is confirmed that NVENC is not a feature of the GPU on Jetson platform.

Comment: jetson-nano has specify hardware for decoding video like `MPEG2, H.264/AVC, HEVC, VP8 and VP9` formats, [look bellow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70611629/1207193). Don't need to use GPU for that!

Answer (score 4):

ffmpeg support has been added to the Jetson platform. From [nvidia's docs](https://docs.nvidia.com/jetson/l4t/index.html#page/Tegra%2520Linux%2520Driver%2520Package%2520Development%2520Guide%2Fmultimedia.html%23wwpID0E0JB0HA):

```
To install the ffmpeg binary package
•Enter these commands:
$ sudo apt install ffmpeg

To get source files for the ffmpeg package
•Enter this command:
$ apt source ffmpeg

To include the ffmpeg library in L4T builds
1.Add the following lines to /etc/apt/sources.list:
$ echo "deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/ffmpeg main main" |  sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
$ echo "deb-src https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/ffmpeg main main" |  sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
2.Enter the command:
$ sudo apt update
```

To be clear, on the standard Jetson image, append

```
deb https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/ffmpeg main main
```

to your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, and then run
`sudo apt update && sudo apt install ffmpeg`
.

Comment: Note that they've only integrated ffmpeg decode support. The patched ffmpeg github repo mentioned in the original question also supports hardware encoding on the jetson.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use [(jetson-ffmpeg)](https://github.com/jocover/jetson-ffmpeg) a ffmpeg patched for jetson-nano

- Jetson nano don't need to use GPU for hardware **decoding** *MPEG2, H.264/AVC, HEVC, VP8 and VP9*.
- Those formats are decoded by **specific video hardware decoder** (`NVDEC`) that can be accessed by L4T Multimedia API that patches the ffmpeg above. That hardware is separated from GPU that can be used by you for other purposes.
- You can also use [@Simon Labrecque](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64149036/1207193) answer if you don't plan using encoding. Although I still prefer the first.

#### Command line hardware decoding *jetson-ffmpeg*

You did something wrong with the above ffmpeg. To use hardware decoding you have to specify the decoder. From their repo [README](https://github.com/jocover/jetson-ffmpeg#supports-decoding) some examples.

- For decoding a H.264 stream/file `ffmpeg -c:v h264_nvmpi -i yourfile\or\stream...`
- For decoding a HEVC stream/file `ffmpeg -c:v hevc_nvmpi -i yourfile\or\stream...`.

#### ZoneMinder

I don't use Zoneminder but [MotionProject](https://motion-project.github.io/) that also uses ffmpeg as a backend library. I have been using 4 IP Cameras without problems for some months already. CPU usage around 20% for 8 RTSP streams (high and low resolutions).

For *ZoneMinder* I am not sure but I think that `DecoderHWAccelName`, `DecoderHWAccelDevice` parameters should do the trick. Specifying for example `h264_nvmpi` or `nvmpi` or whatever needed for your stream. But I can't be precise though because I don't use it anymore. Try their [docs](https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/gettingstarted.html?highlight=DecoderHWAccelDevice%20#adding-monitors) look for those parameters on *adding-monitors section.*